# how to make jQuery mobile nested list remain in the same page while navigating?

Tags: jquery-mobile

On a page which contains, among other content/widgets, a nested list, I'd like the page to keep the same content while navigating through categories, and go to another page only when clicking on a leaf item which has "a href".

For example, this page has "Nested lists" header, and a sidebar:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/lists/lists-nested.html

Clicking on "Animals" should keep the same header/sidebar, eventually add an "animals" divider/header to the list (but not to the page). Same for clicking on "Pets". Only clicking on "Canary" should navigate to another page, with it's own content. This would be similar with http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-alpha.1/docs/lists/lists-collapsible.html (but I need a nested list, not collapsible of lists)

Couldn't find a mention about this on Google or jQ docs. Is it possible and how?